# When to use "-er" vs "-or" as a suffix in verbs - a comprehensive example (a developer's perspective)!

Tags: word-choice, nouns, agent-noun-suffix, agent-nouns

It's been many times when it comes to decide whether to use "**-or**" or "**-er**" as an agent noun suffix to a verb. My native (mother language) is Greek, and I'll try to provide you a way to think before making a decision.
Although both suffixes are correct...but not so much...

Here's how it goes according to the meaning being passed to the reader!

- **USING THE** ***"-or"***

  The "**-or**" is used to either:

  - ASSIGN AN ABILITY to someone.

    For example we say:

    > "*He is the terminat**or***"

    that emphasizes the ability of someone to destroy...
  - DEFINE that someone HAS ALREADY DONE what the verb (prefix) does and also GIVE him some rights over the product of that action. 
    For example we say:

    > "*He is the implement**or** of the SQLite JDBC driver*"

    that emphasizes the one who HAS IMPLEMENTED the SQLite JDBC driver. He has already done it. He has finished this project and that implementation is already being used by client code all over the world. Thus, this also gives him some owner rights over his own project..(his implementation).
- **USING THE** ***"-er"***

  Instead we would use the "**-er**" suffix to either:

  - EMPHASIZE THAT THE ACTION keeps going on (not finished yet) or being maintained at the time of speech:

    > *He's been assigned the SQLite JDBC driver implementation. He is the implementer of the SQLite JDBC driver.*
  - DISTINGUISH the ACTOR OF THE ACTION DESCRIBED by that verb from the OWNER OF THE PRODUCT OF THAT ACTION. (in other words, between the one who ***creates*** something and the one who ***owns*** that same thing). This is being accomplished by using both ***-er*** & ***-or***.

    For example, assume that someone sells his implementation to a company that does the distribution and also the kick start of the implementation & availability to client code all over the world...thus, we say that:

    > *this company (BrandM Corp.) is the "IMPLEMENTOR" of that driver...*

    and we keep referring to the author as:

    > *the original author is the "IMPLEMENTER" (Mr. Someone) of that driver.*

    This distinction helps us separate the real author of the implementation (the assignee) from the project manager or company (the company that is the owner of the implementation (the brand).

### Further Examples

We keen on using the "Adaptor Pattern" instead of "Adapter Pattern" for the Adaptor structural Design Pattern that all it is a structural pattern that "gives tha ability" to the developer to implement a class that will be used to adapt an existing utility functionality to a forced way of accomplishing the exact same functionality. Thus, **the pattern** is called the "***Adaptor*** pattern" and **the implemented class** that conforms to this structural pattern is called "***Adapter***":

- Assume a british man during his holidays in Greece. He has to carry his UK-to-EU mains adapter otherwise no shooties no selfies!
  [image: Adapter design pattern example]

  We refer to it as either:

  - "***the Adaptor implementation for the UK to EU mains sockets***" to *emphasize* the pattern that was used to implement the specific solution (adaptation) or
  - the "***the UK to EU mains Adapter***" because every time it is being used it accomplishes the same functionality. "Carries the mains current from the wall on the one side to the adaptee's pins at the other side". **It is NOT a one-shoot thing**.
- On the other hand we say that:

  "*our lawsuit company is the **adaptor** of the A companies policies to the B companies policies*"
  meaning that:

  "*our company **carried out the adoption once**. No further steps are required after the adoption is accomplished for the specified set of policies assigned to us for the adoption process*".

  "*Every other set of policies would need a different 'care', thus a different adoption*".

  Meaning that the functionality/service being provided ***is always a one-shot thing*** (always in a different unique way).

### Example of a possible argument/misconception (accredited/thanks to @HotLicks)

> Back in the 60s IBM attributed a different meaning to the different spellings. Best I can remember it, they decided that:
>
> - "***-er***" implied something passive (eg, "***receiver***") while
> - "***-or***" implied an active component (eg, "***selector***").

The explanation here is that ***THERE IS NOT*** such a "***selecter***" word, thus the "***selector***" ***IS VALID*** because the "**selection**" process is ALWAYS a ***one-shoot thing*** and differentiates among different options as options differentiate one to each other (by nature).

Comment: There may be some general rules for this, but there are also lots of exceptions.

Comment: Both of these suffixes are pronounced the same -- /-ər/. Whether they are spelled _-er_ or _-or_ is a matter of the individual spelling history of each word; there is not a general rule, and everybody just has to learn each one individually. Or else not care whether it's spelled with an O or an E, since nobody else seems to. After all, the difference has an information value of zero, like the difference between _theater_ and _theatre_.

Comment: @JohnLawler You're half way right! There is a difference in the meaning (only when it comes to choose the way to write it (as i've said)!
Yes it is not a general rule, assuming words like "eraser" where no "erasor" exists!
As far as the other words you've mentioned "theater/theatre" (and let me mention another common one "center/centre" are Greek words and i could definitely support the "-tre" versions if i wanted to empasize their origin "θέατρο" (in Greeklish it is spelt as "theatro") and "κέντρο" (in Greeklish "kentro" or "centro" ;-) ...

Comment: @JohnLawler ...But i don't do that. I use the "theater" and "center" just because there are not so many English words ending with "tre" and also it sounds more English. (and hides somehow the fact that the majority of the English words are Greek. ;-)

Comment: There is no difference in meaning attributable to the spellings _-er_ and _-or_. The spellings are distributed without regard to meaning.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Back in the 60s IBM attributed a different meaning to the different spellings.  Best I can remember it, they decided that "-er" implied something passive (eg, "receiver") while "-or" implied an active component (eg, "selector").

Comment: @HotLicks This is also a good example/distinction that can be also used by someone (company) in order to pass such a difference in the meaning!

Comment: @javase - Actually, a "selector" would carry out it's activity repeatedly.  It was a key component of the "I/O channel" that fed data into and out of a computer.

Comment: @HotLicks - Correct! In another explanation i've read that "-or" comes from French that's why it exists in many english words.

Comment: @Ian MacDonald before down-voting please SEE my edits and explanations about what HotLicks said! Stay in your own world and let us (we the developers) clear out how logic explains some things in order to minimized the interoperability problems that exist in systems developments!
I've created this topic ONLY FOR SOFTWARE/SYSTEM DEVELOPERS. I don't bother how other scientific sectors mesh with -er/-or at all!

Comment: I am a software/system developer. I will never agree that a part of my system is a drivor (i.e. assigned the action of "driving" the bus communication between your client code and the database, by your own rules). You cannot attempt to inject meaning where there is none, especially in a software development environment. When a new person inherits your project, all they will see is a pile of typos; the meanings you have assigned are only present in your own closed ecosystem and they won't be understandable outside of that environment because it is not common usage.

Comment: Are you trying to understand how these suffixes are **actually** used (in which case the answer emerging from these comments is that there is no rhyme or reason to it), or to **propose** that they be used in a certain way (in which case the matter is outside the scope of this site)?